# Python iterate through column add ',' between values and apply to a cell within another column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to iterate through a single column and append a comma ',' to each value and then concatenate all values into a single cell within another column(all cells below this have no value denoted by 'no contents/blank cell'):

```
Raw data:                  output:
ID                         ID new
123                        123,456,789...
456                        no contents/blank cell
789                        no contents/blank cell
```

Code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

#bring in dataset-
DF = pd.read_excel('c:/Desktop/List.xlsx', sheet_name="Sheet1")

DFlist = list(set(DF['ID']))
string = ",".join(map(str,DFlist))

print(string)
```

This produces exactly what I need, however I need to introduce this into the dataframe into a different column.  And currently when I run the following code, I get an error that python pandas does not like my column name:

```
DF['col'] = string + DF['col'].astype(str)
```

aside from the fact that the above code is most likely incorrect, pandas will not accept:

```
DF['col']....
```

Comment: Is this data in a file? Is it an a dataframe? Can you please clarify, as well as show your current effort?

Comment: Hello, this would be pulled in from either a sql query or a .csv file and the most likely used as a dataframe, but if there is a more straight forward option vs using a dataframe i would be open to that as well-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
df['col'] = ''  # initialize a blank column
df['col'].iloc[0] = ','.join([str(ident) for ident in df['ID'].unique()])
```

Testing on a small dataframe, that puts all IDs, separated by commas, into the first cell of the `'col'` column, and the rest will be blank. Note that using `set()` means that your IDs will not necessarily be in any particular order, which is why I used `df['ID'].unique()` instead.